# Why does a subcomplex of a cell complex being closed mean the characteristic map has an image in the subset?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was trying to learn some Algebraic Topology though I haven't got very far yet so I would greatly appreciate it if you gave as simple answer as possible.
On page 7 of Hatcher he says:

> Since $A$ is closed, the characteristic map of each cell in $A$ has image
>   contained in $A$

Why is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, the previous version of the answer was not correct. It's even easier: preimage of $A$ is a closed subset of $D^n$, which contains all interior points. Any such closed subset is necessarily entire $D^n$.